# Using Virtual Domains with WordPress and Cherokee Web Server

Tags: rewrite, wordpress, cherokee

I'm trying to configure WordPress to work with Cherokee Web Server. The multi-site set up in WordPress is `yyy.com` and uses 'sub-domains'. Thus, I have sites like `aaa.yyy.com`, `bbb.yyy.com` - they all work fine so far.

However, I have another completely different domain: `abcde.com`. Within WordPress, the sub-domain set up is `abcde.yyy.com`. When a public user accesses `abcde.com`, it cannot properly be redirected to the WordPress sub-domain `abcde.yyy.com`.

How do I set up Cherokee to properly redirect virtual domains to WordPress? That means, the domain facing public would be `abcde.com` but WordPress would want to see `abcde.yyy.com` to properly return the correct content for the specific site.

(I tried and it always get redirected to something like this: "http://yyy.com/wp-signup.php?new=abcde.com")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set up your DNS to point both the sub-domain and mapped domain properly.

**Then, in Cherokee...**

```
Create a Source (under Sources)
 Type: Remote Host
 Nickname: Cherokee
 Connection: [the ip and port which can reach Cherokee Web Server]
```

**In WordPress.. (you need to enable multisite first).**

```
Create the WordPress Site
My Sites -> Sites -> (Add New)
add the site...

Then, go to -> My Sites -> Network Admin -> Sites -> (select site)
in Settings, change only these 2 fields:
 Home: http://abcde.com
 Fileupload Url: http://abcde.com
```

**Then, back in Cherokee...**

```
Create a new Virtual Server and assign it to your sub-domain, eg. "abcde.yyy.com"
This is a PHP Virtual Server, so follow the instructions from Cherokee Help Manual,
and test it to make you can get WordPress running. 
References:
http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_php.html
http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_wordpress.html
```

**Now, you can go back to WordPress...**

```
Go to site... configure, etc.
(set permalinks properly, etc.)
```

**Finally, back in Cherokee...**

```
Create yet another another Virtual Server - this time a HTTP Reverse Proxy server for your mapped domain name
 Nick: abcde.com
 Document Root: path to WordPress directory

... in Basics
 Directory Indexes - empty

... in Rule Management
 remove all except Default
 change Handler to HTTP Reverse Proxy, 
  Request -> URL Rewriting
   Add RegEx: ^/(.*)$
   Substition: http://abcde.yyy.com/$1
   ... click Add
 Back-end Servers 
  Balancer -> Round Robin
 Assign Information Sources
  Application Server -> "Cherokee" (as an Information Sources)
```

**Lastly, restart Cherokee! That's it!**