# WordPress MU Domain Mapping

Tags: wordpress, domain, cherokee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Virtual Domains with WordPress and Cherokee Web Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/441879/using-virtual-domains-with-wordpress-and-cherokee-web-server)

I'm trying to configure domain mapping for WordPress with Cherokee and I came across a WordPress Plugin called "WordPress MU Domain Mapping".

Reference: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Question: is the plugin absolutely necessary to for domain mapping from the web server to WordPress?

Comment: I have found the solution. There is absolutely no need to use this plugin. (I will provide the answer within a few hours.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it here:
[Using Virtual Domains with WordPress and Cherokee Web Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/441879/using-virtual-domains-with-wordpress-and-cherokee-web-server)

Yes, the "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" is completely redundant - it is **not** necessary to use this plug to get domain mapping working.